# how to use the value of a variable as the name of another variable

Tags: r, rename

In R , how to use the value of a variable as the name of another variable

for example:

```
SCE<-function(i){
  #x<-paste0("SCE",i)
  x<-c(i,i+1)
  return (x)
}

x<-paste0("SCE",1) 
y<-SCE(1)


paste0("SCE",1)=SCE(1)
cat("SCE",1)=SCE(1)
```

How can I make the value of variable x (string) as the name of another variable y (unknown data type)?
Here, the final result I want to get is a variable named SCE1, its type is numeric, and its value is 1 2

The problem I actually encountered is: I have a repetitive code that I want to use a for loop to complete, but every time I complete it, I want to save the result as a variable so that I can use it later.

```
SCE<-function(i){
  #x<-paste0("SCE",i)
  x<-c(i,i+1)
  return (x)
}

for (i in 2:9) {
  x<-paste0("SCE",i) 
  y<-SCE(i)
}
```

Every time the for loop is completed, I hope to get a variable of SCE+number, whose value is the result of the corresponding SCE function

[image: renamne]
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understand your question correctly, `assign` could be an option :

```r
SCE<-function(i){
  assign(x = paste0("SCE",i), value = c(i,i+1), envir = parent.frame())
}
SCE(1)

SCE1
#> [1] 1 2
```

Answer (score 1):

The value of

```
paste0("SCE", 1)
#[1] "SCE1"
```

We may need the brackets as well

```
x <-paste0("SCE(", 1, ")")
```

and then do an `eval(parse`

```
eval(parse(text = x))
#[1] 1 2
```

which is same as executing the function

```
y <- SCE(1)
y
#[1] 1 2
```

---

If the OP wanted to get the values from "SCE1", then extract the function part and the input argument separately

```
match.fun(sub("\\d+", "", x))(as.numeric(sub("\\D+", "", x)))
#[1] 1 2
```

---

If we want to create objects in the global environment (not recommended), an option is `list2env`, though it is better to store it in a named `list`

```
lst1 <- setNames(lapply(1:5, SCE), paste0("SCE", 1:5))
list2env(lst1, .GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for your quick answer, but in fact I didn't seem to state my question clearly.
The problem I actually encountered is: I have a repetitive code that I want to use a for loop to complete, but every time I complete it, I want to save the result as a variable so that I can use it later.

Comment: @Alen Have you checked the solution at the end with `match.fun`

Comment: @Alen Do you want to create object names SCE1, SCE2 etc with the input 1, 2, ..

Comment: If you use for example`lapply`, you can loop over a block of code that returns the last statement to you in a list when done. Could you work with that? Creating dynamic variable names is seldom the right answer and a good indication that something can be done better in another way